# datetimepicker jquery script is not running after deployment of asp. net mvc 2 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datetime

I have deployed asp.net mvc 2 application successfully. but let say there is view fro create user where I used code for datetime picker :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

    });

    </script>

This is working fine. But same code I used on Edit view for the user . but not working . why should not this ?
Edit View script for datetimepicker is :

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If  you are editing on the same page, try using a `class` instead of `id` for the element under question:

```
$(function() {
$('.DateOfBirth').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

You need to give the element attribute of class:

```
<.... class="DateOfBirth"
```

Comment: where have to give this element ?

Comment: @Lalit: The element you have assigned the id to `DateOfBirth`. Replace `id` with `class`.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but I have code like this :<div class="editor-field float-left">
                <%= Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"), new { @class = "wide" })%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextElectionDate)%>
            </div> so i am in confusion. out of this what i have to give there?